# Force user to call Object :__call__

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to only allow a user invoke any/all object methods when the object itself is called?

Looking for different examples on how to do this

Some example code

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, x=1):
        self.x = x
    def __call__(self, x=1):
        self.x = x
        return self
    def get(self, y):
        return (self.x * y)

t_obj = Test()

t_obj(2).get(1) # Acceptable case
t_obj.get(1) # Raises exception
t_obj().get(2) # Acceptable case
```

Comment: ... what about `x = t_obj(); x.get(1)`? Anyway, you could use a flag in your object, like `self.called = False` that is set to `True` in `__call__`, and then in `get` you can check `if not self.called: raised NotCalledException`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you just blew my mind - need to think on that. However won't self.called always be set to True going forward?

Comment: It sounds like what you want is your object to be a class and you only want to access values after you instantiated an object from it, is that it?

Comment: @user3166881 sure... you can set it back to `False` though. I really don't know what you are trying to accomplish here. I don't think there is any particularly elegant way, except maybe returning a proxy-object, as suggested in a now-deleted answer. I suspect this is the [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you *actually trying to accomplish*?

Answer (score 0):

#### Right way to do it

It seems to me that what you want is for `t_obj` to actually be the class and not an instance of `Test`. It then gives the exact behavior you showed in your example.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, x=1):
        self.x = x

    def get(self, y):
        return (self.x * y)

t_obj = Test # not an object, actually a class

t_obj(2).get(1) # 2
t_obj.get(1) # Raises exception
t_obj().get(2) # 2
```

In particular, the exception states that `method get() must be called with Test instance`, i.e. you had to call `t_obj` to instantiate an object before being able to call `get()`, which is exactly what you want.

#### Fun way to do it

Although, suppose you really need your objects to be callable, here is a hacky way to get this working. It replaces the `get` method of your object when called, replacing a placeholder which only purpose is to raise.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, x=1):
        self.x = x

    def __call__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.get = lambda y: self.x * y
        return self

    def get(self, y):
        raise AttributeError('call object first')

t_obj = Test()

t_obj.get(1) # Raises exception
t_obj(2)
t_obj.get(1) # 2
```

Comment: Got any ideas on how to enforce this?

Comment: What do you mean? It is enforced here.

Comment: I added a precision stating why this is precisely the behaviour you want.

Comment: sorry, let me be more specific. There's nothing stopping a user from invoking a Test instance is what I meant

Comment: If you remove `__call__`, your user can no longer call the instance. It can only update `x` directly which is the proper way to do this. Do you have a problem in mind that specifically needs you to call objects?

Comment: In other words, what extra behaviour do you need in your context, because that does exactly what you need.

Comment: Honestly, it spurred from another discussion - this is mostly a what if exercise

Comment: I see. My recommendation would be to follow the above example. Relying on a kind of "lock until this was called" is bad practice because it can be very hard to debug, it would be kind of a hack. On the other end, making the first call an instantiation and the subsequent ones attribute setting (`obj.x = 2`) is not only  the proper way to do, it will also let your user know explicitly at what stage of your process they are at, while with `__call__`, it is not obvious if the object was called already

Comment: Point noted - Thank you Olivier

Comment: Although, for the sake of the thought experiment, I added how I would hack my way around it.

Comment: when you said "hack" you weren't kidding